# iScroll overlaps textarea touch or click to write

Tags: jquery, cordova, textarea, phonegap-plugins, iscroll

Im developing a Demo on Phonegap to iOS and Android and i choose iScroll to make pages scrollables, it works fine but i must generate the iScroll after de DOM elements are created, so the iScroll overlaps the textarea touch and make is unwritable by left click or touch.

I tried to when the DOM element is created make it readonly and after generate the iScroll remove the readonly attr, it does well but dont works, iScroll contiue overlaping the textarea write function by touch or click.

Anyone have any idea what i can do? Or how to solve it?

Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I remember struggling with the same issue. I fixed it by stabbing the iscroll.js, but I'm unfortunately unable to provide code right now.

However, check this commit https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll/commit/feb0088a996a28ebd0a7a37ee7b9e31a50a4a58e . It resembles the fix I made in my case, so it probably fixes the issue.

Comment: It solves at my test on chrome !!! Thanks mate!!! I need to test it on samsung and ipad tablets, but i think it will works. Thanks again!

Comment: great link, i tried and used onBeforeScrollStart: function (e) { var donothing; } and this worked for me, then saw this, great thanks @zvona